# Where should functions that control the window attributes go in a MCV design pattern for Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, class, design-patterns, tkinter, controller

I'm designing a Tkinter app and I really want to apply proper structure to my application. One thing I still struggle with is where certain methods should go.
In this case, I have a function that centers the main window once the GUI runs so that the user sees the window in the middle of their screen. I'm thinking that this function should be a method in the Controller class but I also thought it could go in the Model class because it's technically logic? Or maybe it shouldn't be in a class at all?

I don't want to get to broad, but is there generally a good way to think about where too place methods? Like a checklist of sorts to go through when making design assumptions regarding the methods put into a class?

## CODE

```
import tkinter as tk

class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class View:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master_frame = tk.Frame(master)


class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View(self.root)

    def run(self):
        self.root.title("My App")
        self.middle_of_screen(1350, 750)
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.root.iconbitmap('images/an_image.ico')
        self.root.mainloop()
    
    # Not exactly sure where it's most conceptually correct to put this method
    def middle_of_screen(self, window_width, window_height):
        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (screen_width // 2) - (window_width // 2)
        y = (screen_height // 2) - (window_height // 2)

        self.root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Controller()
    c.run()
```

Comment: I’ve always thought that the MCV model is a chimera...

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: That is an illusion to use this development model.

Comment: It definitely isn't, there are tons of resources on it. I'm not sure why you're posting if you have no plan to answer my question or at least explain your point. It's not helpful in the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to parametrize where the window goes, its geometry and positioning belongs to the GUI.
The controller could be used to manage interaction with the user, in case you wanted to make the positioning an actionable property; however, the controller should not even be aware that the GUI uses `tkinter` or some other framework...
In a more elaborate app, the controller could be in charge of loading an ini file that is passed to the GUI.

The positioning, geometry, or anything related to the view has nothing to do with the model in any case. The model ignores both the controller and the GUI.

In your case, I would suggest something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View()
        self.view.start()


class View(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.master_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.title("My App")
        self.middle_of_screen()
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.iconbitmap('images/an_image.ico')

    def middle_of_screen(self):
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (screen_width // 2) - (window_width // 2)
        y = (screen_height // 2) - (window_height // 2)

        self.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}')

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, it cleared things up for me!

Comment: If I use your code I get the error "TypeError: create() argument 2 must be str, not tuple"

Comment: Yes, remove the calling parens in `class View(tk.Tk)` - I edited the code. It is pseudocode BTW, there is nothing to run really - It is there to illustrate how to design the various components of your app.

Comment: Oh yeah for sure, I was only looking at it from a structural perspective; I just want to understand how a window was created. I did have one more question though; is it better to make a frame in the view class? I thought of maybe creating separate Frame classes that would hold specific widgets. I.e TopFrame etc. than call those classes with ```self.top_frame = TopFrame()```

Comment: I feel like if I keep handle all of the widgets and frames in the View class, it would get quite large

Comment: It depends on the size and scope of your app; beyond the most simple programs, it is Frame within Frame, within Frame, all the way down.